# Calling a function if QWizardPage has a specific value

Tags: qt

I am creating a wizard with QWizard object:

```
IntroPage::IntroPage(QWidget *parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
{
//    QWizardPage *page = new QWizardPage;

    setTitle(tr("Introduction"));

    QLabel *intro = new QLabel(
                tr("bla bla"));
    intro->setWordWrap(true);

    QLabel *next = new QLabel(
    tr("click next."));
    next->setWordWrap(true);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(intro);
    layout->addWidget(next);
    setLayout(layout);
}
int IntroPage::nextId() const
{
    return pageList::LIST_SOFTWARE;
}
```

I override `nextId` function to go to a specific page using ENUM.

I would like a function to be called if I am in the next page for example. For this I wrote the following code:

```
SecondPage::SecondPage(QWidget *parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
{
     ...
    findApp();
     ...
}
```

But the function is called immediately on the first page. How can I just enable function call only on second page?

EDIT: Pages are `QWizardPage` type

Answer (score 0):

There's functionality with `QWizard` to do per page validation, you should be able to extend that to do it.